# ConcurrentModificationException inside PublishResult - ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

Some source-code I have inherited sometimes throws a ConcurrentModificationException on this line:

```
for (String c : filteredList) {
```

body:

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    ArrayList<String> filteredList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
        clear();
        for (String c : filteredList) {
            add(c);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

How should I prevent this error from happening?

Comment: Normally I just use the filtered list directly instead of a further round of iteration. You can always keep a reference to the full list for when the filter criterion is null/empty.

Comment: Admittedly that's much harder to do with `ArrayAdapter` because much of its handling of the items is internal and not available to you (and the API sadly doesn't have a `setItems(List<T>)` method, which is truly unfortunate). I think you can make your life easier by extending BaseAdapter instead--the things ArrayAdapter provide are pretty trivial to recreate.

Comment: What would a hot-fix to this fatal issue be above while using ArrayAdapter w/o extending BaseAdapter?

Comment: Honestly, using reflection to set the `mObjects` field of the `ArrayAdapter` class directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*ConcurrentModificationException:*

> It is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it...

A Hotfix solution, would be cloning the `ArrayList<String>`, before iterate it :

```
ArrayList<String> filteredList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values.clone();
```

You need to consider that if the list is large, you're going to consume twice as much RAM during that period of time.

btw, i would run first the validations, before map / clone your list, switching your first 2 lines, as a performance improvement:

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
        ArrayList<String> filteredList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values.clone();
        clear();
        for (String c : filteredList) {
            add(c);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps! Cheers,

Comment: I'm getting `'clone()' has protected access in 'java.lang.Object'` error on `clone()`. What should I do?

Comment: I Edited your answer using https://stackoverflow.com/a/16044940/6444297